How do I detect the user switching accounts from within an Excel js add-in?
I'm building an Excel Js add-in taskpane that provides basic features for free and advanced features for licensed users. For that, I need to know who the current user is to look up if they have a license. I can get the current user with SSO and getAccessToken to enable/disable the advanced features and that works well.
But in Excel, the user can switch between multiple accounts using the dropdown in the window title bar and I find that whenever I call getAccessToken, I'm always given the account they first opened Excel with, not the one they currently have selected. Furthermore, I really should be changing my UI when they switch accounts (e.g. if one account is licensed and the other isn't), so I need an Excel application event to tell me that - I don't see one mentioned in the Excel or Office object model documentation.
To test this, I had a button that calls getAccessToken, decodes the jwt and displays the user name. I changed the logged in account and clicked the button again. I expected the jwt to contain the new account details but it gave me the original one again.

I believe that Office caches the jwt returned from getAccessToken until it expires. Try waiting at least an hour between changing the logged in account and clicking the button again. See what happens.

Hi Rick, yes I have to wait for the expiry- shouldn’t Office clear the cached credentials if I switch user account; isn’t that a security risk my addin’s user can access someone else’s data without the addin knowing anything about it?

It may be a scenario so odd that it wasn't considered: You have users A and B who are not different IDs of the same human being and whose data should be mutually private. But somehow they are both logged in. User A finishes his business with the add-in and then walks away without closing the add-in or the workbook. User B sits down at the same Excel and add-in session, switches to his ID in the ribbon drop down and then runs an add-in function that calls getAccessToken. Is this really your scenario?

No, the actual scenario is a developer doing production support. I have my normal Id which doesn’t have production access and a separate prod-support account. When there’s a prod incident, I request my prod support account to be enabled for a few hours (all activity then keystroke-logged) and I can then check and fix the prod issue. But my addin doesn’t see or get notified of the account switch, so can’t see the prod data.

Scenario 2 is an accountant working for multiple SMEs, given a guest login for each tenant to access their sharepoint and popular web-based accounting software through an Excel addin.  They start Excel with their personal account and switch to their ClientA account. When done with ClientA, they switch Excel to ClientB and start their work - but the addin didn’t get told and is still showing ClientA’s accounts, which the accountant uses and saves to ClientB’s sharepoint.

Neither of these seem to be cases of the user accessing data they don't have permission to see. It seems that the workaround in both cases is to restart Excel (and maybe all you have to do is restart the add-in). You could raise this issue on the office-js repo. Maybe there's already a better alternative.
